# CoffeeScript Intellisense

Tags: visual-studio-2010, coffeescript, visual-studio-2012

I use Visual Studio for development and I am quite used to Intellisense. But when writting CoffeeScript you don't really get any Syntax Checking or Intellisense.

Is there a plugin for VS that would allow this?

Thanks

Comment: You can get syntax coloring/checking but nothing more, code completion for coffeescript do not exists in any IDE AFAIK

Comment: @Guillaume86 So TypeScript would be an alternative? Its relatively new though.

Comment: Yes if you want the full IDE exerience (code completion/refactoring/etc) typescript can do it, there is also C# to javascript compilers (Saltarelle: http://www.saltarelle-compiler.com/) if you don't mind your generated javascript to be less readable (coffeescript generated code have also a bit of that problem).

Comment: @Guillaume86 Thats interesting.. do you mean any .NET to JS? Like VB.NET -> JS? If so thats so post it as answer so ill accept it. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have more than syntax checking/coloring with coffeescript (on any IDE) AFAIK.

As an alternative, you can use TypeScript to get the full Visual Studio tooling support (and stay close to the javascript), or some transcompilers that transform code to javascript, for C# there is [Saltarelle](http://www.saltarelle-compiler.com/) and for CIL (.NET bytecode, so compatible with any .NET language), I just found [JSIL](http://jsil.org/) but I have no idea how well it works.

Note than the generated code "look" can be important for debugging and using external libraries get a bit of work to be included in Typed languages.

For js code readability I would recommand TypeScript (similar to coffeescript, even easier, but less powerfull as a language). 
Saltarelle code looks readable (didn't tried a lot), for JSIL I have no idea.

A list of languages that compiles to JS: https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/wiki/List-of-languages-that-compile-to-JS

Comment: Are there any builds avaliable for JSIL?

Comment: Sorry I don't know I never used JSIL but it doesn't look like a post build task exists ATM, you would have to create one

Comment: "TypeScript (similar to coffeescript, even easier, but less powerfull as a language)" - none of that is true, sorry. Nevertheless I do recommend TS.

Comment: I was speaking about generated code similarity (compare a TS and a CS class generated code for exemple). A lot of language constructs available in coffeescript are not available in TS (the opposite is not true, except for `module`), it makes it in my opinion a less powerfull language.

Comment: WebStorm parses CoffeeScript like js based on text analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Webstorm and all of the JetBrains IDEs recently added some code completion and refactoring support. It knows what methods are in my own classes and will prompt to complete as I type. The red squiggly underline compile as you type is not quite there yet but it is coming. I bet Webstorm is the first to implement CS source map also. They have added so much in the last 11 months.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2b96d16a-c986-4501-8f97-8008f9db141a

Here is another: http://chirpy.codeplex.com/

I think this should do what you want.

Comment: These only add compilation, not intellisense.