# Javascript reference and Intellisense in Visual Studio 2013 .coffee files

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, coffeescript

Just started using Web Essentials and love its support of .coffee files.  Big problem however:  In Visual Studio, if you add the following reference to the top of a .js file, Visual Studio will include intellisense for the items in the referenced file:

```
/// <reference path="../../js/knockout-3.1.js" />
```

So, while writing my code I can type something like `ko.` and intellisense shows me all the functions knockout has to offer.

However the above XML reference is not allowed in .coffee files and in fact keeps them from being compiled.  I can put the following in a .coffee file:

```
# @reference ../../js/knockout-3.1.js
```

This will compile but I lose the intellisense in Visual Studio.

How can I "include" other .js files as a reference and trigger intellisense in a .coffee file?

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently supported.

See this stack overflow question:
[CoffeeScript Intellisense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13377398/coffeescript-intellisense)

Also see this suggestion from web essentials:
https://webessentials.uservoice.com/forums/140520-general/suggestions/3782958-coffeescript-intellisense

Answer (score 0):

I use VS2015. The way i do it is update the "references.js" file (right click on that file and click update)
[see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKxI4.png)